# Find the number of occurences for a matched document in lucene

Tags: elasticsearch, search, lucene

We are using Lucene for code content search. we are indexing the files in a project using our own Custom Analyser . We are having trouble in getting the number of occurrences for a matched file .

We have got the exact number of occurrences per file when we used a **BooleanQuery**( A **phraseQuery** with must clause) while searching. 
Now we have added another two more queries with the previous one like a **BooleanQuery**( A **phraseQuery** with must clause + A **prefixQuery** with must clause). For this Query we are getting the match results accurate but we are getting the number of occurrences per file as 2 always. 
We are using the below code for getting the number of occurences

```
public class SearchTermFrequencyCollector implements Collector {


private IndexSearcher searcher;
private HashMap<String, Integer> result = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
public SearchTermFrequencyCollector(IndexSearcher searcher){
    this.searcher=searcher;
}

public HashMap<String, Integer> getSearchTermFrequency(){
    return result;
}
@Override
public boolean needsScores() {
  return true;
}

@Override
public LeafCollector getLeafCollector(LeafReaderContext context) throws IOException {
  final int DOCID = context.docBase;
  return new LeafCollector() {
    Scorer scorer;
    @Override
    public void collect(int doc) throws IOException {
      int numOccurrencess = scorer.freq();

      LOGGER.log(Level.INFO,"DOC_ID ::: "+DOCID);

      Document document = searcher.doc(DOCID+doc);
      result.put(document.get(Constants.INDEX_FIELD_FILE_PATH), numOccurrencess);
    }

    @Override
    public void setScorer(Scorer scorer) throws IOException {
        this.scorer = scorer;

    }
  };
}
```

}

We are using the above class getting matched files with the following code.

```
        indexReader = getIndexReader(indexDir);
        msearcher = new IndexSearcher(indexReader);
        SearchTermFrequencyCollector searchtermfreq = new SearchTermFrequencyCollector(msearcher);
        msearcher.search(resultQuery, searchtermfreq);
        HashMap<String, Integer> resultMap = searchtermfreq.getSearchTermFrequency();
        searchDetails = new JSONObject(resultMap);
        hits = resultMap.size();
        resultDetails.put("hits", hits);
        resultDetails.put(indexType, searchDetails);
```

For Querying the we use the following code

```
        searchString = searchString.toLowerCase();
        QueryParser qp = new QueryParser(IndexConstants.INDEX_FIELD_CONTENT, CodeCustomAnalyzer.getdefaultInstance());
        qp.setDefaultOperator(QueryParser.Operator.AND);
            Query contentQuery = qp.createPhraseQuery(IndexConstants.INDEX_FIELD_CONTENT, searchString);
            resultQuery.add(contentQuery, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
        if (fileExtn.length() > 0) {
            BooleanQuery.Builder ExtnQuery = new BooleanQuery.Builder();
            for (int i = 0; i < fileExtn.length(); i++) {
                String extn = fileExtn.getString(i);
                Query extnQuery = new TermQuery(new Term(IndexConstants.INDEX_FIELD_FILE_EXTN, extn));
                ExtnQuery.add(extnQuery, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
            }
            resultQuery.add(ExtnQuery.build(), BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
        }
        Query filePathQuery = new PrefixQuery(new Term(IndexConstants.INDEX_FIELD_FILE_PATH, workingPaths));
        resultQuery.add(filePathQuery, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
```

Sample docs :

Doc1 :

> When a Roman General is betrayed, and his family murdered by an emperor's corrupt son, he comes to Rome as a gladiator to seek revenge.

When searched for

> Roman General i am getting scorer.freq() in collect function as 2. But there is only one occurences. If i add only a single query like say contentquery instead of adding both ExtnQuery , filePathQuery i am getting the result as expected i.e 1 occurence.

Comment: could you provide as well sample docs, so it could be easy to test